# Browsing svn repo code?

Tags: svn

Is there a tool which lets you view the source code a svn repo?

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Edit : I just want to browse the repos which does not have some interface to browse the code.

Answer (score 2):

There's some PHP based interfaces for viewing and browsing one or several svn repos.

My favorite one is [websvn](http://websvn.tigris.org) have a look and let me know if this is useful for you.

Comment: +1 for websvn - very easy to set up, and uses Geshi for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine it wit tracking system "Trac", see http://trac.edgewall.org/